# Cisco ASA WebVPN RDP Plugin Fullscreen

Tags: vpn, ssl, cisco, rdp, cisco-asa

I am using a ASA5520 with 8.2.2(ED) Image and the RDP Java Plugin for Termialserver connections. The version of the Plugin is 1.1.1. "rdp-plugin.090915.jar" and "rdp2-plugin.090211.jar"

everything is working fine, except the fact that clients are not able to do fullscreen.

I already tried different combinations of bookmarks like:

rdp://ts-server-ip?geometry=1280X1024&FullScreen=true

rdp://ts-server-ip?FullScreen=true
etc..

but with no effect. Anyone got this to work?

unfortunatelly a solution with smart-tunnels is not an options, because clients do not have permission to run activeX scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it working but only if the used client is the RDP one launched by Active X and not the Java One - i.e you used WebVPN from Internet Explorer and have security settings allowing Active X

I guess it doesn't affect Java version, I never get it working when Java client loads.

Comment: you've been right, it isn't possible without activeX. I found this in the help screen:

Parameters that only take effect for the ActiveX client are:

    * RedirectDrives - set to true to map remote drives locally
    * RedirectPrinters - set to true to map remote printers locally
    * FullScreen - set to true to start in FullScreen mode

Answer (score 1):

Good Syntax is:

`rdp://ts-server-ip/?geometry=1280x1024&FullScreen=true`

You have forgot a slash betwen Ip-address and Parameters